# How to Display Colour Grid in Different Orientations?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to display a grid in different orientations in Python is there another way to do this vertically, diagionally etc? I also sometimes get an error saying "local variable 'error' referenced before assignment" for some reason too, whereas in another Flask program I've worked on this was not a problem I encountered. Currently the grid displays the colours horizontally.

EDIT - So I have managed to resolve the issue with the referenced before assignment error, it turns out it was an indentation issue. I have attempted to change the colours on the grid placing the value with the variable cointaing the colour instead, this does nothing. I've also added a if request method == 'GET' below the POST request method and stating to abort if a get request is made.

Still I have no clue as about approaching how to re-arrange the grid on a POST request. I added in a request.form['type.h-stripes'] which returns a bad response along with shuffle being undefined when I followed the example stated in the documentation.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import time
import random

app = Flask(__name__) # creates applications instance
app.config.from_object(__name__) # loads configuration from this file, flaskr.py



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
#print ("time.time(): %f " % time.time())
#print (time.localtime(time.time()))
curent_time = (time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))

if request.method == 'POST':
    error = None
    type = request.form['type'] # takes the name value in the html

# Colour 4 being the last colour specified in the array, cahnging displaycolur1 (as an example) to #000000 will force the colour to display as a black colour as it is in hex value
    randomcolourr1 = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    displaycolu1 = ('#%02X%02X%02X' % (randomcolourr1(),randomcolourr1(),randomcolourr1()))

    randomcolourr2 = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    displaycolu2 = ('#%02X%02X%02X' % (randomcolourr2(),randomcolourr2(),randomcolourr2()))

    randomcolourr3 = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    displaycolu3 = ('#%02X%02X%02X' % (randomcolourr3(),randomcolourr3(),randomcolourr3()))

    randomcolourr4 = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    displaycolu4 = ('#%02X%02X%02X' % (randomcolourr4(),randomcolourr4(),randomcolourr4()))

    randomcolourr5 = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    displaycolu5 = ('#%02X%02X%02X' % (randomcolourr5(),randomcolourr5(),randomcolourr5()))

*EDIT*    if request.form['type.h-stripes']: # if request.form contains the type name and h-stripes value being selected
    tablehori = ('color0, color1, color2, color3, color4'.split()) # takes colour values from the table td elements
    shuffle(tablehori) # not defined
    print (tablehori) # prints to console

return render_template('index-example.html', error=error, curent_time=curent_time, displaycolu1=displaycolu1, displaycolu2=displaycolu2, displaycolu3=displaycolu3, displaycolu4=displaycolu4, displaycolu5=displaycolu5)



if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)


<form method="POST">
    <div class="settingpanel">

        <label for="color_0">Color 1</label>
        <input type="color" name="color0" id="color_0" value="{{ displaycolu1 }}">

        <label for="color_1">Color 2</label>
        <input type="color" name="color1" id="color_1" value="{{ displaycolu2 }}">

        <label for="color_2">Color 3</label>
        <input type="color" name="color2" id="color_2" value="{{ displaycolu3 }}">

        <label for="color_3">Color 4</label>
        <input type="color" name="color3" id="color_3" value="{{ displaycolu4 }}">

        <label for="color_4">Color 5</label>
        <input type="color" name="color4" id="color_4" value="{{ displaycolu5 }}">

    </div>
    <div class="settingpanel">

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="h-stripes"
               id="type_h-stripes"  checked >
        <label for="type_h-stripes">h-stripes</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="v-stripes"
               id="type_v-stripes" >
        <label for="type_v-stripes">v-stripes</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="carpet"
               id="type_carpet" >
        <label for="type_carpet">carpet</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="random"
               id="type_random" >
        <label for="type_random">random</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="diagonal"
               id="type_diagonal" >
        <label for="type_diagonal">diagonal</label>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="show">
</form>
```

Comment: What value should `error` have if the request.method is _not_ POST? You only assign to it in one branch.

Comment: I've replaced the error with a GET request instead, and to abort the request. I have also made a couple of changes such as trying to obtain the value from the radio button when a POST request is sent